# Push item into new array within Ajax method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have the following array

```
var arrayOfResults = []; // Results after like statement
```

I make a call to the database which returns me a json result as shown here:

```
[{
            "id": "{fcb42c9c-3617-4048-b2a0-2600775a4c34}",
            "pid": "{34214CCB-90C3-4D75-958B-5A1D0FBDD971}",
            "ttl": "Easter Bunny",
            "img": "/~/media/Images/Recipes/Easter/Filled Pasta/LF_Baked-Spring-Vegetables-Ravioli_920.ashx?h=910\u0026w=910",
            "url": "Some url",
            "taggedwith": ["{3A54907D-4171-4F4E-8FE8-3A38DA1E874F}", "{6CD78C6B-F435-45EC-BE16-810E80311C23}", "{74528A6F-C40B-4030-A278-A4C9A2F46A47}", "{6DC82B78-61F6-45A0-A63C-EA590BB1057E}", "{E9EF1A41-51D0-403D-9373-37B7A880B251}"],
            "articleddate": "2015-05-02",
            "tname": "Recipe",
            "rbrand": ["{1F6EDA5D-4681-40F0-B455-7C343AC25B72}"]
}, {
            "id": "{2e4b04b6-334f-42e9-afd7-ddc4e08417ad}",
            "pid": "{C611BAC8-E8E0-4693-920B-93BD5EE2386B}",
            "ttl": "Latina Fettuccini \u0026 Summer Sauce with Prawns Recipe",
            "img": "/~/media/Images/Recipes/Latina Fresh/Plain Pasta/LF_Fettuccini-Summer-Sauce-Prawns_920.ashx?h=910\u0026w=910",
            "url": "Some url",
            "taggedwith": ["{3A54907D-4171-4F4E-8FE8-3A38DA1E874F}", "{6CD78C6B-F435-45EC-BE16-810E80311C23}", "{74528A6F-C40B-4030-A278-A4C9A2F46A47}", "{6DC82B78-61F6-45A0-A63C-EA590BB1057E}", "{E9EF1A41-51D0-403D-9373-37B7A880B251}"],
            "articleddate": "2015-05-02",
            "tname": "Recipe",
            "rbrand": ["{1F6EDA5D-4681-40F0-B455-7C343AC25B72}"]
}]
```

On the UI I have a text field, which the user can enter free text.

I call the following ajax method when the user has entered roughly 5 characters, what I'm trying to achieve is I want to perform a like statement on the ttl field within the above array, If the ttl field matches or is like the freeText the user has entered then I want to push that item in to the array 'arrayOfResuts' however I see the alert message found yet it doesn't push the item into the new array, I know this because I alert the length at the end of the ajax call and its 0;

```
var addItem = false;

var freeText = $('#searchKeywords').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'search?t=&s=DateDesc&type=globalsearch&q=',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (searchDataList) {

        console.log(searchDataList)


        for (var i = 0; i < searchDataList.length; i++) {
            addItem = false;

            if (freeText.length > 0) { // Filter on free text

                if (searchDataList[i].ttl.indexOf(freeText) > -1) { // if title contains free text then we need to add it to the arrayOfResults[].

                    alert('found');

                    arrayOfResults.push(searchDataList[i]) // This doesn't seem to work.

                    addItem = true;

                }
            }
        } // End of for loop
    },

    error: function (request, error) {
    }
});


alert(arrayOfResults.length);
```

Now I'm not 100% sure what's actually going wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what the output of  `console.log(searchDataList)` ? Also it is missing a semicolon if this is your actual code.

Comment: Where are you sending `freeText `? Maybe you mean to make the url `'search?t=&s=DateDesc&type=globalsearch&q=' + freeText`,

Comment: @VinnyMannello I've already shown the output of searchDataList its at the top of the question, you were write it was missing a semicolon, i've added that now.

Comment: @Lucas we call the following url to retrieve the data from the cache, we then perform the search based on the results we get back, I know its a bad way of doing it however I don't have much control over the server side unfortunately

Comment: Maybe check `if (freeText.length > 0)` outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alert is running before your AJAX request is complete.

Since the AJAX request is asyncronous the `console.log()` code runs before the success is called and so your not printing the result you want.

To print the results simply print within the success and error functions of the AJAX request. Doing so in the complete function will not help since it runs asyncronously from the others.

Comment: This. Ajax request is asynchronous, so the alert of length is happening before the response comes back.

Comment: @Nayish how would I go about printing the desired results? is there a complete function?

Comment: Print the result within the success function and error function. See updated answer

Comment: @Nayish the `console.log()` is in the success statement... You mean to have the `alert(arrayOfResults.length);` at the end of the success block?

Comment: Yes. Thats what I meant to say

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mentioned you need to handle the data within the success block. You can do it directly like below, or for more complex cases call a new function to handle the data at the end of the success statement.

Update code:

```
var freeText = $('#searchKeywords').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'search?t=&s=DateDesc&type=globalsearch&q=',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (searchDataList) {
        console.log(searchDataList);
        for (var i = 0; i < searchDataList.length; i++) {
            addItem = false;

            if (freeText.length > 0) {     
                if (searchDataList[i].ttl.indexOf(freeText) > -1) {
                    alert('found');
                    arrayOfResults.push(searchDataList[i]);
                    addItem = true; 
                }
            }
        } // End of for loop
        if (arrayOfResults.length > 1) {
           alert(arrayOfResults.length);
           console.log(arrayOfResults);
         }
    },

    error: function (request, error) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your alert will always be 0 because AJAX is asynchronous (the A in AJAX stands for that) and you call your alert synchronously.

What happens is, the ajax request gets the data while the synchron code runs as usual. Now that the ajax request is done clearly **after** you call your alert it cannot log anything that makes sense.

If you want a function to be called when the asynchronous request is done, wheter it was successful or not, use `done`: additionally to `success:` and `error:`. This code will run when the request is done and show you the actual length.

Comment: Adressing the person who downvoted this answer, please elaborate how it is wrong and deserves a downvote.